# Método update com flutter e sqlite gerando erro

Tags: flutter, dart

Bom dia, estou fazendo update no sqlite com Flutter e estou tendo o seguinte erro:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'update' was called on null.
```

Montei o código de acordo com a documentação onde recebo um Model e faço um map dos devidos campos.

```
Future<void> updateCategoria(CategoriasModel categoriasModels) async {
  try {
   await db.update('categoria', categoriasModels.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [categoriasModels.id]);
   } catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  }
 }
```

e a model:

```
class CategoriasModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final int id;
  final String descricao;
  final int isReceita;

  CategoriasModel({
    this.id,
    this.descricao,
    this.isReceita,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {'id': id, 'descricao': descricao, 'isReceita': isReceita};
 }
}
```

as demais função de CRUD estão funcionando normalmente.

Comment: Pela mensagem o erro está na instância do seu database. Em que momento vc inicializa ele? Ele está nulo e chamando o método "update".

Comment: Realmente esqueci de inicializar. Valeu meu amigo.

Comment: vou postar como resposta para deixar registrado para outros dev's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo pois o database não foi inicializado e está com o valor `nulo`. Com isso o método `update` não pode ser utilizado. A solução é fazer a inicialização do `db` antes da chamada do método `update`.

**Exemplo**

```dart
Future<void> updateCategoria(CategoriasModel categoriasModels) async {
  try {
   // Inicialização do Database de exemplo (essa abordagem do exemplo
   // segue a implementação de utilizar um Helper Singleton, não é regra
   // e depende de como o projeto está trabalhando).
   final db = await DbHelper.getInstance().db;

   await db.update('categoria', categoriasModels.toMap(),
      where: "id = ?", whereArgs: [categoriasModels.id]);
   } catch (error) {
    print(error.toString());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Se possível dê um exemplo de como inicializar o _database_, para deixar sua resposta mais completa.

Comment: Acredito que a inicialização depende de como ele implementou o código. Não vejo correto induzir uma interpretação minha para a ocasião ainda mais que ele citou no comentário que esqueceu de inicializar e os demais métodos estão funcionando corretamente. De qualquer modo colocarei um exemplo genérico apenas para referência.